# rails 3 dry unobtrusive javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dry, unobtrusive-javascript

I am changing everything to unobtrusive javascript, since I think it makes things much easier to debug etc.

I've got something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#photos_link').click(function()
  {
    select_tab('main', 'photos', $(this));
  });

  $('#dealership_link').click(function()
  {
    select_tab('main', 'dealership', $(this));
  });

  $('#dealership').hide();
});
```

as you can see I've got 2 very similar constructs, I'd like to dry them out, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two pure-JS refactors:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#photos_link, #dealership_link').click(function(){
    select_tab('main', $(this).attr('id').match(/(.*)_link/)[1], $(this));
  });

  $('#dealership').hide();
});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each(['photos', 'dealership'], function(key, value) { 
    $('#' + value + '_link').click(function(){
      select_tab('main', value, $(this));
    });
  });

  $('#dealership').hide();
});
```

I'd personally prefer the former.

Comment: thanks the second one looks better, it does refactor some code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper method in ApplicationHelper (or the appropriate helper):

```
def select_tab_click_event(tab)
  js =<<JS
    $('##{tab}_link').click(function()
    {
      select_tab('main', '#{tab}', $(this));
    });
JS
  js.html_safe
end
```

Then, call it from your view:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  <%= select_tab_click_event('photos') %>
  <%= select_tab_click_event('dealership') %>
}
```

Comment: In terms of being non-obtrusive, that has everything to do with keeping your presentation layer separate from your page structure and allowing your functionality to gracefully degrade in the absence of JavaScript. Since your question asked how to DRY out your code, I concentrated on removing repetition while keeping the presentation layer separate from anything else. Helpers are intended to assist in generation of views, and I've used a helper to do just that while also removing repetition from your code. Helpers are not meant to contain business logic. That belongs on the model.